# Rock^Paper^Scissors Total Amounts not receiving the updated values...Python

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

So here is my code:

```
import os
import random
import time

def main():
    ### Declarations ###
    items = []
    userItems = []
    machineItems = []
    totalTies = 0
    userWins = 0
    cpuWins = 0

    ### Adding elements ###
    items.append("rock")
    items.append("paper")
    items.append("scissors")

    ### Function calls ###
    replay(items, userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins)
    os.system('cls')
    printResults(userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins)

def replay(items, userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins):
    response = 'yes'
    while (response == 'yes'):
        print("*Please enter only lower-cased words*")

        ### It was a tie! ###
        ## This is also Input Validation for the below loop ##
        print("Do you pick: ",
              "\n\t1. Rock?",
              "\n\t2. Paper?",
              "\n\t3. Scissors?")
        userChoice = input("Object: ")
        machineChoice = random.choice(items)

        if (userChoice == machineChoice):
            print("Another game is to be played.")
            time.sleep(.5)
            print("Seting up...")
            time.sleep(1)

            os.system('cls')

            print("Do you pick: ",
                  "\n\t1. Rock?",
                  "\n\t2. Paper?",
                  "\n\t3. Scissors?")
            userChoice = input("Object: ")
            machineChoice = random.choice(items)

            totalTies += 1
            userItems.append(userChoice)
            machineItems.append(machineChoice)

            os.system('cls')

            while (userChoice == machineChoice):
                print("Another game is to be played.")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("Seting up...")
                time.sleep(1)

                print("Do you pick: ",
                      "\n\t1. Rock?",
                      "\n\t2. Paper?",
                      "\n\t3. Scissors?")
                userChoice = input("Object: ")
                machineChoice = random.choice(items)

                totalTies += 1
                userItems.append(userChoice)
                machineItems.append(machineChoice)

                os.system('cls')

        ### User picked "rock" ###
        elif(userChoice == "rock"):
            if(machineChoice == "paper"):
                print("You chose: ", userChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("The computer chose: ", machineChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("And the verdict is...")
                time.sleep(1.5)

                print("Paper covers rock.")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("You lose.")

                cpuWins += 1
                userItems.append(userChoice)
                machineItems.append(machineChoice)
                os.system('cls')

            elif(machineChoice == "scissors"):
                print("You chose: ", userChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("The computer chose: ", machineChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("And the verdict is...")
                time.sleep(1.5)

                print("Rock crushes scissors.")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("You win!")

                userWins += 1
                userItems.append(userChoice)
                machineItems.append(machineChoice)
                os.system('cls')

        ### User picked "paper" ###
        elif(userChoice == "paper"):
            if(machineChoice == "scissors"):
                print("You chose: ", userChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("The computer chose: ", machineChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("And the verdict is...")
                time.sleep(1.5)

                print("Scissors cuts paper.")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("You lose.")

                cpuWins += 1
                userItems.append(userChoice)
                machineItems.append(machineChoice)
                os.system('cls')

            elif(machineChoice == "rock"):
                print("You chose: ", userChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("The computer chose: ", machineChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("And the verdict is...")
                time.sleep(1.5)

                print("Paper covers rock.")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("You win!")

                userWins += 1
                userItems.append(userChoice)
                machineItems.append(machineChoice)
                os.system('cls')

        ### User picked "scissors" ###
        elif(userChoice == "scissors"):
            if(machineChoice == "rock"):
                print("You chose: ", userChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("The computer chose: ", machineChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("And the verdict is...")
                time.sleep(1.5)

                print("Rock smashes scissors.")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("You lose.")

                cpuWins += 1
                userItems.append(userChoice)
                machineItems.append(machineChoice)
                os.system('cls')

            elif(machineChoice == "paper"):
                print("You chose: ", userChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("The computer chose: ", machineChoice)
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("And the verdict is...")
                time.sleep(1.5)

                print("Scissors cuts paper.")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print("You win!")

                userWins += 1
                userItems.append(userChoice)
                machineItems.append(machineChoice)
                os.system('cls')

        response = input("Replay? ('yes' to continue) ")
        os.system('cls')

def printResults(userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins):
    print("You chose: ", "\n")
    for i in userItems:
        print("\t", i)

    print("The computer chose: ", "\n")
    for i in machineItems:
        print("\t", i)

    print("Total ties: ", totalTies)
    print("User wins: ", userWins)
    print("Computer wins: ", cpuWins)

    gamesPlayed = (totalTies + userWins + cpuWins)
    print("Games played: ", gamesPlayed)

    input("Press [Enter] to continue...")

main()
```

This is just supposed to be a Rock_Paper_Scissors program that restarts if there is a tie, records the `userWins`, `cpuWins`, and `totalTies`. When I run this, all works fine, except for the `userWins`, `cpuWins`, `totalTies` do not receive the updated values, so when I print out the results at the end of the program, to show the user how they did, it will say that `userWins`, `cpuWins`, `totalTies`, and `gamesPlayed` are all 0. I don't understand because the lists `userItems` and `machineItems`, used to show the user what was picked by each side, work but not the previously stated variables. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: List in Python are mutable. Integers are not, You cannot update integer value when it's passed as argument.

Answer (score 0):

List in Python are mutable. Integers are not. Therefore you cannot update integer value by passing it as function argument.

Minimal reproducible code:

```
def f(a_list, an_integer):
     a_list.append(3)
     an_integer += 1
     print a_list, an_integer


l = []
i = 1
f(l, i)  # output: [3] 2
f(l, i)  # [3, 3] 2
f(l, i)  # [3, 3, 3] 2
print l, i  # [3, 3, 3] 1
```

Solution would be to return these values from function and update these integers explicitly.

```
totalTies, userWins, cpuWins = replay(...)
```

Comment: I don't think this relates to mutability of lists - _assigning_ to a_list in your example won't be reflected outside of the function either.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a value to a function in Python creates a copy of the value, it is not possible to update the original function argument by modifying the value within the function:

```
def a(mynumber):
    mynumber = 10

mynumber = 5 
a(mynumber) 
print(mynumber)  # will print 5
```

This works the same even for lists and complex objects - while you can modify call the methods of the object, which may modify its state, you can not replace the actual reference in the caller's code.

One possible solution in your case would be to use globals and do not pass "shared" variables as parameters:

```
userItems = 0
machineItems = 0 
totalTies = 0 
userWins = 0 
cpuWins = 0

def replay(items):
    global userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins
    ...

def printResults():
    global userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help, but I have figured it out.

This is what `main()` and `printResults()` should look like:

```
def main():
    ### Declarations ###
    items = []
    userItems = []
    machineItems = []
    totalTies = []
    userWins = []
    cpuWins = []

    ### Adding elements ###
    items.append("rock")
    items.append("paper")
    items.append("scissors")

    ### Function calls ###
    replay(items, userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins)
    os.system('cls')
    printResults(userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins)

def printResults(userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins):
    print("You chose: ", "\n")
    for i in userItems:
        print("\t", i)

    print("The computer chose: ", "\n")
    for i in machineItems:
        print("\t", i)

    print("Total ties: ", sum(totalTies))
    print("User wins: ", sum(userWins))
    print("Computer wins: ", sum(cpuWins))

    gamesPlayed = (sum(totalTies) + sum(userWins) + sum(cpuWins))
    print("Games played: ", gamesPlayed)

    input("Press [Enter] to continue...")
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help once again, and I do not doubt that these will work! Have a great rest of your day! Python Novice, Ghost_Programmer!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that integers are immutable in python. When you are incrementing the values of the variables `userWins`, `cpuWins` and `totalTies`, the value of the variable is updated inside the `replay` function. Lists, on the other hand, are mutable. Thus, if you modify a list (add or remove elements) inside a function, the changes are reflected outside the function.

There are two things you can do:

1. Set the three integer variables to be globals. This method works, but is not recommended
2. Make the function return the changed the integer values.

   Add the following line in the end of the `replay` function

   ```
   return (totalTies, userWins, cpuWins)
   ```

   Also, modify the line where you are calling the `replay` function to the following:

   ```
   (totalTies, userWins, cpuWins)=replay((items, userItems, machineItems, totalTies, userWins, cpuWins)
   ```

   This code should now work.